# Is there a way to generate a string that can be pasted into Excel with generic formatting (i.e. bullets, in-cell line-breaks)

Tags: php, excel, encoding, utf-8, copy

My client has a website full of data in HTML table form.  A feature of the website is to select various rows from the HTML table and copy the contents of the rows (along with other data) to the clipboard.  The client wants the format of this resulting string to maintain certain in-cell formats, such as line breaks and bullets.

Currently I am using Zero Clipboard with an AJAX callback to generate the content and copy it to the clipboard.  That part is working fine.

I have processed the resulting string to use `"\t"` characters to separate cells in a row and `"\n"` to separate rows.  Past this I am lost.

Is there any way to encode bullet point characters and in-cell line breaks into a UTF-8 string so that formatting is preserved when it gets to Excel?

The web server is running Apache with PHP 5.3.

Comment: wouldn't creating excel files rather than copying and pasting from html to excel be a better apporach?

Comment: Formatting will not be preserved if you're using a tab or comma separated-value file, because that format only supports data without any formatting

Comment: What happens if you generate the content just as HTML, and put all of the data in a HTML table including UL/LI elements for bullet point characters?

Comment: btw have you looked at web queries http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/get-external-data-from-a-web-page-HA010218472.aspx to push stuff into Excel 'properly'? If you can get that to work, it's like to be a lot more reliable than re-inventing it yourself through Javascript, which will inevitably be flaky.

Comment: I agree exporting a file would be easier, but the client has a very specific use case where they want to drop small chunks of data from the website into an preexisting excel worksheet as reference data.

Comment: Generating the content has HTML results in the encoded characters being pasted into Excel, so it's essentially plain text HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came to for this issue was sitting in front of me the whole time.

When you paste HTML code into Excel, it translates all the HTML characters into their entities (<) with the exception of one set...tables.

While I was never able to add bullet points into excel, I was able to create the tables even with some styles like background colors and borders by generating a table element with inline css.  Excel handled the row and col spans correctly and still preserved some formatting.  This met the client's needs and is about as close as I think you can get.